# TCP_NODELAY with persistent socket?

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, persistent-connection, nagle

It seems that I can either get a persistent socket connection with pfsockopen(), or get a normal socket connection with socket_connect() then using socket_set_option() to set TCP_NODELAY. But there is no way to get a persistent socket connection with TCP_NODELAY.

Is there any way to get a persistent socket connection with TCP_NODELAY in php?